# Convert Databricks notebook to .py file in workspace

Tags: python, databricks, mkdocs, aws-databricks

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is that I'm using mkdocs/mkdocs-materials for my documentation. But that tool can't work with notebook type files.

So as a clumsy workaround I'm figuring is to have an intermediate step that creates a copy of the notebook content as a .py file, in the same workspace folder. Have mkdocs build off of those copies. Then delete the copies before pushing.

For example I've got a notebook type object in my workspace. Display looks like this:

```
%sql
select * from something

%sql
select * from something_else

def some_dummy_function():
    print('dummy')
```

When you export a notebook as a source python file via the GUI, you get this with all the tagging for syntax.

```
# Databricks notebook source
# MAGIC %sql 
# MAGIC select * from something
# COMMAND ----------

# MAGIC %sql
# MAGIC select * from something_else

def some_dummy_function():
    print('dummy')
```

I want to get this programmatically, from a notebook in a workspace.

Or if you've got suggestions for the root problem at hand ... all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cobbling together using this as a reference, mainly for the base64 decode idea:

[String search in all Databricks notebook in workspace level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082090/string-search-in-all-databricks-notebook-in-workspace-level)

and this handy package: https://pypi.org/project/databricks-api/

```
pip install databricks-api

from databricks_api import DatabricksAPI
import base64

notebook_context = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext()
databricks_api_instance = DatabricksAPI(
      host=notebook_context.apiUrl().getOrElse(None),
      token=notebook_context.apiToken().getOrElse(None)
  )

response = databricks_api_instance.workspace.export_workspace(
    f"/Repos/me@my_company.com/my_repo/my_notebook",
    format="SOURCE",
    direct_download=None,
    headers=None,
)

notebook_content = base64.b64decode(response['content']).decode("utf-8")

with open("/Workspace/Repos/me@my_company.com/my_repo/new_file_name.py","w") as f:
    f.write(notebook_content)
```

Comment: don't use that package, it's not supported - use new official SDK: https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sdk/

Comment: Ah, appreciate the heads up